# unix vi file edit not working the text just gets capitalized

Tags: unix, vi

Whenever I try to inset and edit text using vi the text is just getting capitalized.

I couldn't enter new text

I do have permissions to edit the file though

Comment: Do you know how to use `vi` as it's not the most obvious text editor I've every used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the server operating system is SunOS 5.10 so it was a little tricky and had to follow this guide from Oracle

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7612/editorvi-14762/index.html

Answer (score 0):

When you first start vi, vim and similar clones, it will start up in "command mode."  To begin "inserting" more text you, not surprisingly, hit the lower case 'i'.

If you are looking to append to the end of the line, try the capital 'A'.

You really should have a look at a tutorial if you're going to use it more than once:  [UC Davis 5 minute tutorial on VI](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/UnixAndC/Editors/ViIntro.html)

Answer (score 0):

As others will say it is not the most intuitive editor to use.
Always make a backup of the file you are going to edit prior to modifying it.

```
To use vi: vi filename
To exit vi and save changes: ZZ   or  :wq
To exit vi without saving changes: :q!
To enter vi command mode: [esc]
```

Helpful link: http://www.cs.rit.edu/~cslab/vi.html